# Wordpress website loading extremely slow

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have a question. I have this website, the ftp looks like this:

[image]

The main website is inside the httpdocs folder. But outside that folder there are like 3 different copies of the website inside the httpdocs folder. Will having so many copies of the main website **OUTSIDE** the httpdocs folder affect the speed of my website **INSIDE** the httpdocs folder. I think it would if it were inside the httpdocs folder but in this case its outside of it, will it affect my websites speed?

**incase you're wondering why i have the copies its because 1 is a backup and one is development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not. First of all check if your server CPU & RAM is not overflowing
But there is so much to do to fix wp speed:

1. Install caching plugin - I would recommend W3cache or WProcket cache. You can find optimal settings online.
2. minify CSS/JS - you can do it using the caching plugin
3. Install autoptimize and "above the fold" plugins for mainpage optimization
4. optimize images - save for web, combine into sprites, use base64
5. install CDN - cloudflare is free but maxcdn have better parameters.
6. Use GTMETRIX to monitor your progress
7. update your `.htaccess` file
8. install p3 performance plugin to check which plugins are slowing you down
9. check if your theme is not causing to much slowing - maybe you can combine css/js files
10. see if you not using too much external files.
11. Reduce number of requests and number of dom elements - use DOM Monster extension in chrome

I will follow this question. update me with your progress and I can give more tips here

Comment: autoptimize does CSS/JS aggregation & minification, so either use that or use the one in W3TC or WPR, but don't let 2 plugins both do minification (it might break things). also if you're using AO, the "maybe combin css/ js files" would already be solved.

Comment: Yes you are right it might brake things. As for the combine  I suggested manually combine files instead of letting the plugin do it

Comment: well .... manually combining works in pre-production stage, but once your site is in production and plugins or theme are updated, your manually combined files are likely to not reflect the updated original JS/ CSS any more, so you would have to re-aggregate those files manually at every update.

Answer (score 1):

Test your server in https://www.webpagetest.org/ and check for which file it take longer time. i don;t think it make any problem out side of htdocs folder

Answer (score 0):

Just check the **WP-Content** folder and check there size of images, try to decrease the size of images.

and check the **RAM** of Server is it free or fully loaded ?

Comment: But a part of the question was if the folders outside the httpdocs is affecting the speed?

Comment: yes, if there is low space on drive then it effects.